# Computing visual "center" of irregular polygon

Tags: centroids, terminology

UPDATE: centroid is fine, my initial implementation was not weighing the edge length.  With that fix all is well.

I am using the centroid to render a marker in the "center" of a parcel, but the marker location is heavily influenced by detailed curves in the geometry.  Parcels on a cul-de-sac, for example, have markers unnaturally close to the cul-de-sac.  Here you can see parcels along a curved roadway have a centroid that is not suitable for locating a marker that represents that parcel:

[image: centroid of parcels]

What term should I be looking for to compute a more suitable location for these markers?  I assume the solution is to simplify the geometry before computing the centroid, but perhaps there is a simpler solution.  I am using GeoAPI via NetTopologySuite.

Comment: The center of the bounding box might be the best option.

Comment: The unit polygon has mass 1 and perimeter of P and each edge line segment has a weight equal to its length divided by P.  A line segment has a midpoint so we find the weighted center using that formula (I think).

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203135/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-visual-center-of-an-irregularly-shaped-pol

Comment: Centroid of largest inscribed circle.

Comment: Pole of inacessability

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "polylabel" and Mapbox provides numerous ports of their polylabel algorithm.  See a C# implementation at https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel/issues/26.  At the time of this answer, the solution looked like this:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using PriorityQueue;

  namespace SkiaDemo1
  {
     public class PolyLabel
     {
        private const float EPSILON = 1E-8f;

        public static float[] GetPolyLabel(float[][][] polygon, float precision = 1f)
        {
           //Find the bounding box of the outer ring
           float minX = 0, minY = 0, maxX = 0, maxY = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < polygon[0].Length; i++) {
              float[] p = polygon[0][i];
              if (i == 0 || p[0] < minX)
                 minX = p[0];
              if (i == 0 || p[1] < minY)
                 minY = p[1];
              if (i == 0 || p[0] > maxX)
                 maxX = p[0];
              if (i == 0 || p[1] > maxY)
                 maxY = p[1];
           }

           float width = maxX - minX;
           float height = maxY - minY;
           float cellSize = Math.Min(width, height);
           float h = cellSize / 2;

           //A priority queue of cells in order of their "potential" (max distance to polygon)
           PriorityQueue<float,Cell> cellQueue = new PriorityQueue<float, Cell>();

           if (FloatEquals(cellSize, 0))
              return new[] { minX, minY };

           //Cover polygon with initial cells
           for (float x = minX; x < maxX; x += cellSize) {
              for (float y = minY; y < maxY; y += cellSize) {
                 Cell cell = new Cell(x + h, y + h, h, polygon);
                 cellQueue.Enqueue(cell.Max, cell);
              }
           }

           //Take centroid as the first best guess
           Cell bestCell = GetCentroidCell(polygon);

           //Special case for rectangular polygons
           Cell bboxCell = new Cell(minX + width / 2, minY + height / 2, 0, polygon);
           if (bboxCell.D > bestCell.D)
              bestCell = bboxCell;

           int numProbes = cellQueue.Count;

           while (cellQueue.Count > 0) {
              //Pick the most promising cell from the queue
              Cell cell = cellQueue.Dequeue();

              //Update the best cell if we found a better one
              if (cell.D > bestCell.D) {
                 bestCell = cell;
              }

              //Do not drill down further if there's no chance of a better solution
              if (cell.Max - bestCell.D <= precision)
                 continue;

              //Split the cell into four cells
              h = cell.H / 2;
              Cell cell1 = new Cell(cell.X - h, cell.Y - h, h, polygon);
              cellQueue.Enqueue(cell1.Max, cell1);
              Cell cell2 = new Cell(cell.X + h, cell.Y - h, h, polygon);
              cellQueue.Enqueue(cell2.Max, cell2);
              Cell cell3 = new Cell(cell.X - h, cell.Y + h, h, polygon);
              cellQueue.Enqueue(cell3.Max, cell3);
              Cell cell4 = new Cell(cell.X + h, cell.Y + h, h, polygon);
              cellQueue.Enqueue(cell4.Max, cell4);
              numProbes += 4;
           }

           return (new[] { bestCell.X, bestCell.Y });
        }

        //Signed distance from point to polygon outline (negative if point is outside)
        private static float PointToPolygonDist(float x, float y, float[][][] polygon)
        {
           bool inside = false;
           float minDistSq = float.PositiveInfinity;

           for (int k = 0; k < polygon.Length; k++) {
              float[][] ring = polygon[k];

              for (int i = 0, len = ring.Length, j = len - 1; i < len; j = i++) {
                 float[] a = ring[i];
                 float[] b = ring[j];

                 if ((a[1] > y != b[1] > y) && (x < (b[0] - a[0]) * (y - a[1]) / (b[1] - a[1]) + a[0]))
                    inside = !inside;

                 minDistSq = Math.Min(minDistSq, GetSegDistSq(x, y, a, b));
              }
           }

           return ((inside ? 1 : -1) * (float)Math.Sqrt(minDistSq));
        }

        //Get squared distance from a point to a segment
        private static float GetSegDistSq(float px, float py, float[] a, float[] b)
        {
           float x = a[0];
           float y = a[1];
           float dx = b[0] - x;
           float dy = b[1] - y;

           if (!FloatEquals(dx, 0) || !FloatEquals(dy, 0)) {
              float t = ((px - x) * dx + (py - y) * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy);
              if (t > 1) {
                 x = b[0];
                 y = b[1];
              } else if (t > 0) {
                 x += dx * t;
                 y += dy * t;
              }
           }
           dx = px - x;
           dy = py - y;
           return (dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }

        //Get polygon centroid
        private static Cell GetCentroidCell(float[][][] polygon)
        {
           float area = 0;
           float x = 0;
           float y = 0;
           float[][] ring = polygon[0];

           for (int i = 0, len = ring.Length, j = len - 1; i < len; j = i++) {
              float[] a = ring[i];
              float[] b = ring[j];
              float f = a[0] * b[1] - b[0] * a[1];
              x += (a[0] + b[0]) * f;
              y += (a[1] + b[1]) * f;
              area += f * 3;
           }
           if (FloatEquals(area, 0))
              return (new Cell(ring[0][0], ring[0][1], 0, polygon));
           return (new Cell(x / area, y / area, 0, polygon));
        }

        private static bool FloatEquals(float a, float b)
        {
           return (Math.Abs(a - b) < EPSILON);
        }

        private class Cell
        {
           public float X { get; private set; }
           public float Y { get; private set; }
           public float H { get; private set; }
           public float D { get; private set; }
           public float Max { get; private set; }

           public Cell(float x, float y, float h, float[][][] polygon)
           {
              X = x;
              Y = y;
              H = h;
              D = PointToPolygonDist(X, Y, polygon);
              Max = D + H * (float)Math.Sqrt(2);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```